# How to update a Firebase child without 'knowing' the parents?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have the following data in the Firebase database. The data is needed to quickly see the 2 players that are in a specific game.

Now I would like to update the name of John Doe (user-ID = UID-1) with one query. Ideally there is a way to do something like this. Obviously this is pseudo-code... :-)

`Firebase.ref('/game-players/*/UID-1').update("John with a different Doe")`

```
"game-players" : {
  "game-1" : {
    "UID-1" : "John Doe",
    "UID-2" : "Donald Trump"
  },
  "game-2" : {
    "UID-1" : "John Doe",
    "UID-3" : "Barrack Obama"
  }
}
```

This could be solved by first checking all the games the player participates in (as that data is available too ass a different branch of the tree), but I do not like the idea of having to generate a lot of different queries based on that data.

Any thoughts that can put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your data structure.

```
players:
|--uidxx
|---- name
|---- surname
|---- ...
|--uidx2
|---- name
|---- surname
|---- ...

game-players :
|-- game-1 : 
|----   uidxx : true,
|----   uidx2 : true,
```

In the `players` node you put all the players with the data (for example the name).
In the `gameplayers` node you only use the `uid` of the players and not the data.
In this way you have only to update the data in the players node without querying all games.

Comment: Hmm... but isn't this contradictory with regards to denormalization and 'the data structure follows your use cases'? I mean: when I want to print a list with all the user names per game, I now need to execute 2 queries...

Comment: It is a flatten data like this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#flatten_data_structures